# Convert sagemaker model (MXNet) to ONNX: infer_shape error

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, mxnet, onnx

## Working

I'm working on sagemaker jupyter notebook (environement: `anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6`).

I run **successfully** this tutorial: https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/MXNetONNXExport.ipynb

---

## Not working

Then, on the same evironement, I tried to apply the same process to files generated by a sagemaker training job. So, I used as input the **S3 model artifact** files, changing some lines of the tutorial code to meet my needs.
I used built in object detection SSD VGG-16 network with hyperparameter image_shape: 300.

```
sym = './model_algo_1-symbol.json'
params = './model_algo_1-0000.params'
input_shape = (1,3,300,300)
```

And `verbose=True` as last parameter in `export_model()` method:

```
converted_model_path = onnx_mxnet.export_model(sym, params, [input_shape], np.float32, onnx_file, True)
```

When I run the code I got **this error** (**verbose output** at the end of the post):

```
MXNetError: Error in operator multibox_target: [14:36:32] src/operator/contrib/./multibox_target-inl.h:224: Check failed: lshape.ndim() == 3 (-1 vs. 3) : Label should be [batch, num_labels, label_width] tensor
```

---

## Question

I was not able to find any solution so far:

- maybe the `input_shape = (1,3,300,300)` is wrong, but I'm not able to
  find it out;
- maybe the model contains some unexpected layer or so;

Does anybody knows a way to fix this problem or a workaround to use the model on a local machine? 

(I mean without having to deploy to aws)

---

The **verbose output**:

```
  infer_shape error. Arguments:
  data: (1, 3, 300, 300)
  conv3_2_weight: (256, 256, 3, 3)
  fc7_bias: (1024,)
  multi_feat_3_conv_1x1_conv_weight: (128, 512, 1, 1)
  conv4_1_bias: (512,)
  conv5_3_bias: (512,)
  relu4_3_cls_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_weight: (24, 512, 3, 3)
  relu4_3_loc_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  relu7_cls_pred_conv_weight: (24, 1024, 3, 3)
  conv3_3_bias: (256,)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_weight: (16, 256, 3, 3)
  conv4_3_weight: (512, 512, 3, 3)
  conv1_2_bias: (64,)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_conv_weight: (256, 128, 3, 3)
  conv4_1_weight: (512, 256, 3, 3)
  relu4_3_scale: (1, 512, 1, 1)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_conv_bias: (256,)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  conv2_2_weight: (128, 128, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_weight: (24, 256, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_conv_bias: (256,)
  conv5_1_bias: (512,)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_conv_bias: (256,)
  conv2_1_bias: (128,)
  conv5_2_weight: (512, 512, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_weight: (16, 256, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_weight: (16, 256, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_conv_weight: (512, 256, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_2_conv_1x1_conv_bias: (256,)
  multi_feat_2_conv_1x1_conv_weight: (256, 1024, 1, 1)
  conv4_3_bias: (512,)
  relu7_cls_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  fc6_bias: (1024,)
  conv2_1_weight: (128, 64, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_conv_bias: (512,)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_weight: (24, 512, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_5_conv_1x1_conv_bias: (128,)
  relu7_loc_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  conv3_3_weight: (256, 256, 3, 3)
  conv1_2_weight: (64, 64, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_2_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  conv1_1_bias: (64,)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  conv4_2_weight: (512, 512, 3, 3)
  conv5_3_weight: (512, 512, 3, 3)
  relu7_loc_pred_conv_weight: (24, 1024, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_conv_weight: (256, 128, 3, 3)
  conv3_1_weight: (256, 128, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_weight: (16, 256, 3, 3)
  relu4_3_loc_pred_conv_weight: (16, 512, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_conv_weight: (256, 128, 3, 3)
  fc7_weight: (1024, 1024, 1, 1)
  conv4_2_bias: (512,)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_weight: (24, 256, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_3_conv_3x3_relu_cls_pred_conv_bias: (24,)
  conv2_2_bias: (128,)
  conv5_1_weight: (512, 512, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_3_conv_1x1_conv_bias: (128,)
  multi_feat_4_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  conv1_1_weight: (64, 3, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_4_conv_1x1_conv_bias: (128,)
  conv3_1_bias: (256,)
  multi_feat_5_conv_3x3_relu_loc_pred_conv_bias: (16,)
  multi_feat_4_conv_1x1_conv_weight: (128, 256, 1, 1)
  fc6_weight: (1024, 512, 3, 3)
  multi_feat_5_conv_1x1_conv_weight: (128, 256, 1, 1)
  conv3_2_bias: (256,)
  conv5_2_bias: (512,)
  relu4_3_cls_pred_conv_weight: (16, 512, 3, 3)
```